Secure the approval data inside sharepoint list
We have a SharePoint list named Contracts, with these main fields:-

ID

Title

Number

Approval Status


now we granted our Operation employees + Operation managers Contribute permission on the list. then we build Power Apps that will only show the "Approval Status" field in-case you are inside the Operation Managers Teams. this will work if we guarantee that users will only use power apps, and will not modify the list using REST API or SharePoint list view UI. so to secure this process (make sure that only Operation Managers can modify the Status field), we found 2 approaches:-

Separate the Contract list into 2 lists, one for the contract info , while the other for the approval info. and grant the Operation team contribute on the first list and read-only on the second list. while the operation manager will have contribute on the 2 lists. this will secure the back-end.

second approach, is to have one contract list and set all users to have Read-Only permission, then interact with the list from power apps using a power automate flow that get called from power apps, and which runs using a service account:-



in this case we can define the business rules inside the power automate flow, and make sure that you can not modify the "Approval Status" field unless you are inside the Operation Managers group.
so my question is which appraoch to follow and why?
Thanks

My recommendation is option 1. With two separate lists, you are in full control of who can access these lists.
Your PowerApp can pull the data from the restricted list, and the PowerApps is only published to people who also have access to the restricted list.
That will be easy to maintain within Power Apps and regular SharePoint permissions. You won't need any workflows and you won't need to break or set permissions for any individual list items.
It is also easier to handle if staff change roles. A new staff member gets added to the AD group that grants access to the restricted list and to the Power App. Done.

thanks for the advcie
